# A very interesting polylog integral $\int_{0}^{1} {\rm Li}_{r}(x(y-y^2))\,dy $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How do we find this one $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} {\rm Li}_{r}(x(y-y^2))\,dy $ ?

I have tried by part but I can't substitute $y-y^2$ in any way, as it would change both the limits to 0. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k k!^2}{k^r (2k+1)!}$ .Why is it interesting ?

Comment: Can we really evaluate it ? This integral or the summation is a key to many summations. Evaluating this one will be a way to find the sum of some other series. That's why I've encountered this while summing a lot of sums.

Comment: I agree with @user90369 : it's much better not to use superlatives, in mathematics as in common life, especialy when there is nothing spectacular... Understatement is an alternative : "I have tried to compute a closed form formula for this modest integral..."

Comment: What is the range of values for $r$ ? Is for example $r=2$ of interest for you because this is the value of the polylog where there are many many formulas...

Comment: Yes I do agree with you but some problems which would carve out ways for another solutions can be called "interesting" . Actually for r=2 , yeah I can , I wanted to know if there is a generalisation.

Comment: 1) You may have noticed the humor in my remark. 2) What is the range of values of $x$ ? 3) In the case $r=2$, I find (as you seem to have also noticed) with Mathematica a not-to-complex expression for a primitive function of $Log_2(x(y-y^2))$ out of which it is easy to obtain a value of the definite integral of this function between $y=0$ and $y=1$.